# Defining a custom Maru type in Elixir and using it to fetch Json POST entity

Tags: elixir, maru

I want to define a custom type in Maru and use it to parse JSON post entity, and use it further to execute a sql statement. But I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

---

Here's my custom type

```
defmodule Maru.Types.Volume do
  use Maru.Type

    @type length :: Float
    @type breadth :: Float
    @type height :: Float

end
```

This type has to be used in the router

```
defmodule My.Router.Box do
   use Maru.Router
   alias My.Repo.Box, as: :DB

   namespace :select_volume do
      params do
         requires :volume, type: Volume

   post do
      volume = DB.getBoxWithRequiredVolume(params)
      conn |> put_status(200) |> json(volume)
   end
end
```

And then used here for sql query

```
defmodule My.Repo.Box do
  import Ecto.Query
  require Logger

  def getBoxWithRequiredVolume(params) do
      volume = params[:volume]
      query = from box in My.Box,
          select: (
              %{id: box.id}
          ),
          where: (box.length == ^volume[:length] and box.breadth == ^volume[:breadth] and box.height == ^volume[:height])
      query |> My.Repo.all
  end
end
```

This is the entity for the REST query:

```
http://localhost:8880/select_volume
{
 "volume":{
    "length": 20,
    "breadth": 5,
    "height": 5
 }
}
```

Error:

```
%Maru.Exceptions.InvalidFormatter{param: :volume, reason: :illegal,
value: %{"breadth" => 5, "height" => 5, "length" => 20}}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The above code doesn't work. I'm unable to use Volume to parse the entity

Comment: This is still not a question. Also, do you receive any error? What happens? Please, either restate your question according to the rules of this site, or it will be closed.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not a custom type, you just need make your params like this:

```
params do
  requires :volume, type: Map do
    requires :length, type: Float
    requires :breadth, type: Float
    requires :height, type: Float
  end
end
```

and then, you can get `params` with value: `%{breadth: 5.0, height: 5.0, length: 20.0}` from the request you sent above.

Answer (score 0):

`String`s aka `binaries` and `Atom`s are not the same in Elixir.

The value you are passing has binaries as it’s keys. The formatter expects atoms (e.g.: `volume[:length]`).

Also, I would suggest you to have an explicit test for `My.Repo.Box.getBoxWithRequiredVolume` ensuring it returns what is expected.

---

*Sidenote:* the source code of where this particular exception is thrown might shed a light: it’s [`Maru.Runtime.do_parse/3`](https://github.com/elixir-maru/maru/blob/078944fdfb71880f4839025829824ab7405ae265/lib/maru/runtime.ex#L36).